# Destructor called in method that pass value to variable

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, destructor

I am creating pseudo std::vector. I want to be able to declare variable `Matrix B` and after that assign value to it, passed by another `Matrix` variable.
`Matrix` have constructor, that allocate memo

```
Vect(int size, char name) : name(name), size(size), store(new int[size]){}
```

and destructor that deletes it on end of var lifecycle

```
~Vect(){
  std::cout << "memo located: " << name << std::endl;
  delete[] store;
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the method that used to return value returns it with destructor called

```
  Vect operator- (){
    Vect b(size,'C');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      b.store[i] = -store[i];
    }
    return b; // <- here it calls destructor!!!
  }
```

I try to do this:

```
  Vect m2;
  Vect m1 = Vect(10, 'A'); 
  m2 = -m1;
```

And I get this error:

```
memo located: C
-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, 
memo located: A
memo located: C
a.out(46158,0x109e71dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9162401850: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(46158,0x109e71dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

How can I walk around it with functionality saved?
My code:

```
#include <iostream> 

class Vect { 
  int *store; 
  int size = 0; 
  char name;

  public:
  Vect operator- (){
    Vect b(size,'C');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      b.store[i] = -store[i];
    }
    return b;
  }

  int *getPointer(){
    return store;
  }
  int getSize(){
    return size;
  }

  bool set(int i, int v){
    if (i >= size)
      return false;
    store[i] = v;
    return true;
  }

  Vect(){}
  Vect(int size, char name) : name(name), size(size), store(new int[size]){}
  ~Vect(){
    std::cout << "memo located: " << name << std::endl;
    delete[] store;
    }
}; 


int main(int argc, char **argv){ 
  Vect m2;
  Vect m1 = Vect(10, 'A'); 

  int i = 0;
  while(m1.set(i++, i));

  m2 = -m1;
  int size = m2.getSize(), *ptr = m2.getPointer();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    std::cout << ptr[i] << ", ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Also `while(m1.set(i++, i));` may lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).  *More than one modifications of the same scalar in an expression without any intermediate sequence point (until C++11) that are unsequenced (since C++11)*.

Comment: 1, 2: No, It does not answer my questionq
3: I know, I'm not asking that...

Comment: (1, 2) yes it does `m2 = -m1;`  calls the build-in assignment operator that copies the raw pointer `store` and leaves `m1` and `m2` both thinking they own memory causing double delete.  Also `Vect m1 = Vect(10, 'A'); ` calls the copy constructor - same problem only here `m1` is now holding a pointer to already deleted memory.  Either use `std::vector` internally for the memory buffer or `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @Krasnay Danil Yes, that precisely answers your question. Did you even read what they linked? Understand the rule of 3 (5 from C++11 onwards) and you will know whats going wrong.

Comment: @RichardCritten No,  `Vect m1 = Vect(10, 'A');` has no such problem. I know what's happening there, my question is How To Make It Possible? Seems nohow. Because `operator-` breaks OOP logic, so probably I should define `operator=`.

Comment: @Eric Yes, I read the link. I know how it works. I'm asking is there any walkarounds?

Comment: @Krasnay Danil There is no walkaround. If you write a class where the default copy/move is not sufficient you basicly have three choices: You either implement the copy and move operations that you need, you delete them to prevent them from being used or you can try to change the implementation of your class so can use the default ones. If it's not possible to implement your class in such a way and you want to have copy/move then there is simply no way around implementing the rule of 5

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to implement "copy-and-swap idiom". You need to swap the data from `b` (temp object) into your object, then the temporary one is safely destroyed.

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BMccSpz03cpGuG6S

Answer (score 0):

What I'm trying to do is impossible achieve. Either `operator-` should invert original object or I should implement `operator=` and modify `operator-`

Comment: I recommend having the operator- changing the object and a copy constructor that takes an object and makes a copy out of it. So `m1 = -m2` would work as expected.